# Wrong count of "Views"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, specific-question

The count of "Views" for [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11013/is-it-inappropriate-to-ask-about-a-companys-dress-code-during-an-interview) question isn't displayed correctly. It was 3, when it should be at least 4, assuming that every person viewing the question voted for the first answer.

Did this happen previously?

Edit: It has fixed by now.

Comment: Thanks @Shog9 - I didn't think to tag it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens from time to time (more votes than views). The view count is not updated in true real-time; there is some caching.

More of an explanation of how the view count works is [available here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90187/167443).